# '_get_timezone' was not declared when trying to compile using MinGW

Tags: windows, qt, mingw, thrift, qt4.8

I use QtCreator 2.6 with Qt 4.8.4 and trying to compile my code on Windows 7 x64 by MinGW (4.4, 32bits).

I included [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) to my project, and got errors on file `thrift\windows\GetTimeOfDay.cpp`:

```
'errno_t' was not declared in this scope
'_get_timezone' was not declared in this scope`
'_get_daylight' was not declared in this scope
```

Have you ideas how yo solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got working idea. We must avoid all `GetTimeOfDay`, and delete from project files `GetTimeOfDay.cpp, GetTimeOfDay.h` and use `<time.h>`'s function `gettimeofday`.

If someone will get same error, I can provide more code.

*And, of course, if you'll find better way to solve that problem (or point, that problem is solved in further versions of Thrift) -- feel free to post here!* :)